# Writing a program that takes a string as an argument and returns a new string in which all of the letters of the word are in random order

Tags: python

The programs works unless 11 or more characters are entered as input.

```
import random

word = input("Enter a sequence of characters: " )
prenum = ""
rword = ""

for val in range(len(word)):
    num = random.randint(1, len(word))
    if val == 0:
        prenum += str(num)
        rword += word[num - 1]
    else:
        while str(num) in prenum:
            num = random.randint(1, len(word))
        prenum += str(num)
        rword += word[num - 1]
print(rword)
```

Comment: why don't u raise Exception when word >= 11 or directly restrict it by setting a condition of len(word) <= 10

Comment: What's your question? Are you asking why there's an error only when the length of the string is > 10?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no comments, and I'm not quite sure how you're trying to shuffle the letters.

But shuffling a list is built into a Python.  You just have to convert your string into a list, shuffle it, and then convert it back into a string.

```
x = list(word)
random.shuffle(x)
result = ''.join(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use shuffle() function

https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

Example

```
import random

list = [20, 16, 10, 5];
random.shuffle(list)
print "Reshuffled list : ",  list

random.shuffle(list)
print "Reshuffled list : ",  list
```